# How i can print difference with percentage

Tags: python, function, percentage

I am doing text game practice for school and we have to make four different functions to it. I have done health points system, and now i would like to print how many percentages player have used of total amounta.

This is my hp system:

```
def hela(player_health, hit):
    return player_health - hit

player_health_points = 15
dog_hit_value = 4
pistol_hit_value = 15
brasnuckles_hit_value = 3
punch_hit_value = 1
kick_hit_value = 2
player_health_points = hela(player_health_points, dog_hit_value,)
player_health_points = hela(player_health_points, brasnuckles_hit_value)
print('You have ' + str(player_health_points) + ' HP left!')*
```

**And this is what i have done now and lost my rest brains with it:**

```
def hp_left_percentage(x,y):
    vastaus = x - y
    return vastaus

health = 16
tulos = hp_left_percentage(health,player_health_points)
print(tulos)
```

**Questions:**

- Why i have to add one for def hp_left_percentage health getting it show right value?
- Now def hp_left_percentage shows me how much player have healt, with numeric amount. How i can get function print it percentages?

I hope you can understand what i mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the percentage of health left, not just the absolute number? Right now your `health_left_percentage` just shows the number difference in HP. To calculate the percentage you can change it to this:

```
def hp_left_percentage(x,y):
    # I assume, 'y' is the damage here.

    vastaus = (x - y) / x
    print(f'You have {vastaus:.0%} HP left!')
```

This way the function will automatically calculate the percentage and return it in proper formatting. I suggest reading up on f-strings for a clean way to display strings with variables the way you want them to be.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I misunderstood you.

**EDIT**
If the player gets hit two or more times, then you should store intial HP in a global variable and change the function like this:

```
initial_hp = 100


def hp_left_percentage(x, y):
    vastaus = (x - y) / initial_hp
    return vastaus


perc_left = hp_left_percentage(x, y)
print(f'You have {perc_left:.0%} HP left!')
```

Comment: This indicates how much your health just decreased, not the percentage left from the starting value.

Comment: How so? If x=100, initial HP, and y=30, the damage, the function returns 70%, as it is.

Comment: Then if you lose another 20, it should display you now have 50% (if I am guessing the OP's intentions correctly). Your code will display 71%

Comment: Also, surely, for the function to be meaningful, it should `return` the value, not just print it.

Comment: So, in my case x = player_health (15) and y = player_health_points. Why i cannot just write x - y / x ? And that code still tells me 47% which means how much is spent, not how much is left? Sorry if i misunderstand something. I started my school two months ago and before that i was html newbie and know nothing of python.

Comment: @Osmankaapa no problem, and I am sorry that I'm not understanding you correctly. Let's try to clear up: in your function ```hp_left_percentage``` x is player health initially and y is player health now?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
def hp_left_percentage(x,y):
    vastaus = x - y
    percentage = '{0:.2f}'.format((vastaus / x * 100))
    return vastaus
```

Comment: def hela(player_health, hit):
    return player_health - hit
    
def hp_left_percentage(x, y):
    vastaus = 1 - (x - y) / initial_hp
    return vastaus

player_health_points = 15

dog_hit_value = 4

player_health = 15
initial_hp = 15

player_health_points = hela(player_health_points, dog_hit_value,)

perc_left = hp_left_percentage(player_health, player_health_points)

print(f'You have {perc_left:.2%} HP left!')

Answer (score 0):

I was in vacation, so have not writed here. Thanks for all answers.

This is what i have done.

```
def hela(player_health, hit):
    return player_health - hit

def hp_left_percentage(x, y):
    vastaus = 1 - (x - y) / initial_hp
    return vastaus

player_health_points = 15

dog_hit_value = 4

player_health = 15
initial_hp = 15

player_health_points = hela(player_health_points, dog_hit_value,)

perc_left = hp_left_percentage(player_health, player_health_points)

print(f'You have {perc_left:.2%} HP left!')
```